# Comparator.comparing(...).thenComparing(...) find out which fields did not match

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I am trying to compare two objects of same class and the goal is to compare them as well as identify which fields didn't match.

Example of my domain class

```
@Builder(toBuilder=true)
class Employee {
     String name;
     int age;
     boolean fullTimeEmployee;
}
```

Two objects

```
Employee emp1 = Employee.builder().name("john").age(25).fullTime(false).build();
Employee emp2 = Employee.builder().name("Doe").age(25).fullTime(true).build();
```

Comparing both objects

```
int result = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
                       .thenComparing(Employee::getAge, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
                       .thenComparing(Employee::isFullTimeEmployee, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
                       .compare(emp1, emp2);
```

result will be `0` because `name` & `fullTime` fields are not matching with each other.

But I also want to produce a list of fields which didn't match.. like below

```
List<String> unmatchedFields = ["name","fulltimeEmployee"];
```

Can I do it in a nicer way, other than bunch of `if() else`

Comment: Not with a baseline `Comparator`.  You could build your own class that implements both the `Comparator` logic and collection of unmatched fields, if you wanted.

Comment: You said *result will be 0 because name & fullTime fields are not matching with each other.* but that is incorrect. The result will be a positive number, because `"john"` is greater than `"Doe"` and the comparator stops there returning that comparison. Do you actually want something more like `equals()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [DiffBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/DiffBuilder.html). It can report which items are different.

```
DiffResult<Employee> diff = new DiffBuilder(emp1, emp2, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE)
       .append("name", emp1.getName(), emp2.getName())
       .append("age", emp1.getAge(), emp2.getAge())
       .append("fulltime", emp1.getFulltime(), emp2.getFulltime())
       .build();
```

`DiffResult` has, among other things, a `getDiffs()` method that you can loop over to find what differs.

Comment: that is a nice class. but this means you lose all of the `Comparator::comparing`, etc, java-8 methods, as far as i understand.

Comment: @Eugene you say this as if using `Comparator::comparing` was an advantage.

Comment: @Holger but isnt it? At least you get used to those methods and take it for granted being there. What am I missing?

Comment: @Eugene the code of this answer also ensures that the methods are there for granted. Besides that, you’re now describing method references, which is an entirely different thing than abusing `Comparator::comparing` for a task that is not about comparing at all.

Comment: @Holger I see. I re-read the question and think I understand your point. It indeed looks like there is no need at all for `Comparator`, to begin with.

Comment: @Holger thank you for the previous comments. What a silly, silly mistake. I was so caught up into trying to write a wrapper around `Comparator` that totally lost the `null` and the fact that OP's code and question are bad. thank you again.

Comment: This could probably work for me. `diff.getDiffs().stream().map(Diff::getFieldName).collect(Collectors.toList())` this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Also, thanks for suggesting this handy/cool class in Apache library.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think you understand how comparing().thenComparing() works. The result in your case won't be 0. The comparator compares the first statement, if they are equal it goes to the thenComparing() and so on. The result will be 0 if and only if all comparison()/thenComparing() are also equal. I actually wrote about this a few days ago: http://petrepopescu.tech/2021/01/simple-collection-manipulation-in-java-using-lambdas/

Anyway, back to your question, I think you are looking for an equal() where it also returns what fields were not equal. Here is a quick prototype.

```
public class Pair<T, U> {
    private Function<? super T, ? extends Comparable> function;
    private String fieldName;

    public Pair(Function<? super T, ? extends Comparable> function, String fieldName) {
        this.function = function;
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }
}
```

And the actual comparator:

```
public class MyComparator {
    List<Pair> whatToCompare = Arrays.asList(
            new Pair<Employee, String>(Employee::getName, "name"),
            new Pair<Employee, String>(Employee::getAge, "age"),
            new Pair<Employee, Double>(Employee::isFullTimeEmployee, "fullTimeEmployee")
    );
    public List<String> compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
        List<String> mismatch = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Pair pair:whatToCompare) {
            int result = Comparator.comparing(pair.getFunction()).compare(e1, e2);
            if (result != 0) {
                mismatch.add(pair.getFieldName());
            }
        }

        return mismatch;
    }
}
```

Comment: this makes it a bit ugly since you need to pass the field name; though you can find it out.

Comment: Yes, you can find out the field name, but I did not want to overcomplicate things. OP can do the needed enhancements if he feels like

Comment: The approach of using `Function` is not bad, however, I don’t get why you then return to the OP’s abuse of `Comparator`. Instead of `int result = Comparator.comparing(pair.getFunction()) .compare(e1, e2);  if (result != 0) { … }` you can use a straight-forward `Function<? super T, ?> f = pair.getFunction(); if(! Objects.equals(f.apply(e1), f.apply(e2))) { … }`. Then, your code does not require the property values to be `Comparable`.

Comment: I just assumed that he had to use the comparator as part an exercise or that he wanted to use the comparator. @Holger

Answer (score 0):

`Comparator` itself has no ability to discover out the differences, it only compares two objects of the same type and returns `-1`, `0` or `1`. This is the interface contract.

To discover the actual differences, you need to use Reflection API to get the fields, compare the equality of their real values of two passed objects and let the differences be listed. Here is a generic implementation:

```
public class Difference<T> {

    T left;
    T right;

    //all-args constructor omitted

    public Set<String> differences() throws IllegalAccessException {

        // fieldName-field as a key-value  for the left and right instances
        Map<String, Field> leftFields = Arrays.stream(left.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
            .peek(f -> f.setAccessible(true))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Field::getName, Function.identity()));
        Map<String, Field> rightFields = Arrays.stream(left.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
            .peek(f -> f.setAccessible(true))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Field::getName, Function.identity()));

        // initialize Set as long as two fields cannot have a same name
        Set<String> differences = new HashSet<>();

        // list the fields of the left instance
        for (Entry<String, Field> entry: leftFields.entrySet()) {
            String fieldName = entry.getKey();
            Field leftField = entry.getValue();
            // find the right instance field matching the name
            Field rightField = rightFields.get(fieldName);
            // compare their actual values and add among the differences if they aren't equal
            if (!leftField.get(left).equals(rightField.get(right))) {
                differences.add(fieldName);
            }
        }
        return differences;
    }
}
```

```
Employee emp1 = Employee.builder().name("john").age(25).fullTime(false).build();
Employee emp2 = Employee.builder().name("Doe").age(25).fullTime(true).build();
        
Set<String> differences = new Difference<Employee>(emp1, emp2).differences();
        
System.out.println(differences);
```

> `[name, fullTimeEmployee]`